# How bad an $L_1$ function can get in terms of having $\operatorname{esssup}$ as $\infty$ at many places?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, singularity

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $L_1$ function (i.e., $\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx<\infty$) with $\operatorname{esssup} f=\infty$. Think of functions like $\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$ for example (If you want to be pedantic, you can define $f(x)=0$ to be zero at the points where the functions blows up). For the first function we have singularity at $x=0$ and for the second one we have singularities at $x=0,1$.

In general I can always cook up some function $f$ that has singularity in a given set of finite points and still be in $L_1$. Something like
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\prod_k |x-a_k|}}$$
should work.

> My question is do there exist a function $f\in L_1([0,1])$ such that this essential supremum is attained on a dense set? More precisely the converse is: For $f\in L_1([0,1])$ do there exist an open interval $I$ of $[0,1]$ such that $f_{I}$ has a finite essential supremum?

My guess is that it is not true. Given a function $f\in L_1$, I believe that the "points" where essential supremum is attained are isolated. But I can neither prove or disprove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this completely answers your question but if $(r_n)$ is an ennumeration of rationals in $[0,1]$ then $f(x)=\sum_n \frac  1 {2^{n}} \frac  1 {\sqrt {|x-r_n|}}$ defines an integrable function which is (essentially)  unbounded on every open interval.

Note that (by Tonelli's Theorem)  $\int f(x)dx=2\sum \frac  1{2^{n}} (\sqrt {|1-r_n|} +\sqrt {r_n}) <\infty$ since $\sqrt {|1-r_n|} +\sqrt {r_n}$ is bounded. Hence $f(x)<\infty$ for almost all $x$.

Comment: How would this work? Don't the rationals have zero measure?

Comment: Is your function at all well defined? Can you give me at least one irrational for which the series you wrote for $f(x)$ at all converge? And why converge? It should depend on the enumeration too.

Comment: @Max My function is finite almost evrywhere and integrable. I have added a proof.

Comment: In your calculation of $\int_0^1 f$ you seem to be using the FTC across a singularity. You end up with a sum that could be negative? Also, you don't mention the MCT, which seems important in this problem.

Comment: @zhw. Do you know Fubini/Tonelli Theorem? The interchaege of integral and sum is justified by this theorem. This kind of question  cannot be answered using just basic Calculus. We need measure Theory for this.

Comment: @zhw. Computation of $\int_a^{b}\frac  1 {\sqrt {|x-c|}}d$ where $a <c<b$ is very elementary and standard.

Comment: Of course it is elementary, that's why I knew your original answer had problems.

Answer (score 0):

Define

$$g(x)= \chi_{(0,1)}(x)\cdot x^{-1/2}.$$

Let $q_1,q_2,\dots $ be the rationals in $(0,1).$ Now define, for $x\in [0,1],$

$$f(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{g(x-q_n)}{2^n}.$$

Then $f:[0,1]\to [0,\infty]$ is measurable, and by the MCT

$$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^1\frac{g(x-r_n)}{2^n}\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n} \int_{q_n}^1 (x-q_n)^{-1/2}\,dx.$$

The $n$th integral equals $2(1-q_n)^{1/2}\le 2.$ It follows that $\int_0^1 f<\infty.$ So $f\in L^1.$ But near and to the right of each $r_n$ we have $f(x) > (x-r_n)^{-1/2}/2^n.$ Thus the essential supremum of $f$ is $\infty$ on any subinterval of $[0,1]$ of positive length.